# AutoFill code from OTP SMS in the input field HTML for example in Safari

Tags: html

How can I set up [auto-complete](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element) code from OTP SMS in Safari at the time of Captive Portal for Hotspot Mikrotik?

The problem is that a person does not have time to remember the 6-digit OTP code from SMS, then exit the Captive Portal, see the code in iMessage and then re-tries to log in to the Wi-Fi network, but the old session is already "rotten" and he again needs to enter the phone number and send the OTP SMS code

In HTML I wrote `<input type="tel" id="single-factor-code-text-field" name="password" autocomplete="one-time-code" autofocus>`, and in SMS I send `<#> Your SMS-code: {$code}`, but no magic happens.

Comment: Hi, not sure if this is still relevant but it depends on the sms-send server if it is able to send such an SMS. Furthermore, check [this](https://github.com/wicg/sms-one-time-codes) for the standards of the OTP-sms

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a solution to your problem. According to [these](https://wicg.github.io/sms-one-time-codes/) docs, such an sms should have the following markup:

> In the following origin-bound one-time code message, the host is "example.com", the code is "747723", and the explanatory text is "747723 is your ExampleCo  authentication code.\n\n".
>
> "747723 is your ExampleCo authentication code.
>
> @example.com #747723"

After testing that worked for me. So in order to make the 'magic' happen, the message you are sending should look like this:

> {$code} is your wi-fi login code.
>
> @yourwebsite.com #{$code}

Hope this can help you or someone in the future!

Comment: Does that also work for subdomains? Would I need to put the sub domain in there? 
So, lets say my domain is "https://www.cooldude.com".. BUT, the actual input page is on "https://noway.cooldude.com".... which does the SMS message use? @cooldude.com or @noway.cooldude.com?

Comment: @jamesemanon not sure. I guess that would work as well. My advice is to just test it on multiple mobile browsers.

Comment: From my experience it does not work for subdomain, in that case the domain should be noway.cooldude.com or you will get a "DOMException: OTP retrieval was cancelled." There is also the option that the iframe with the input, in that case you could use a secondary @hostname always at the end of the sms.